# comparing NSDate with [NSMutableArray objectatIndex:i]

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I am have a function called ..

```
-(BOOL)isDateOkForHistory:(NSDate *)dtHist
{
    bool dateOkForHistory = false;

    for(NSInteger i=0;i<m_histCount;i++)
    {
           if(dtHist > [m_dtHistory objectAtIndex:i])
           {       
               //execute some condition.....
           }
     }
}
```

here m_dtHistory is a NSMutableArray.......So my doubt is whether the if statement which i am checking is right..?

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate objects should be compared using `compare:` method.
Example:

```
if ([dtHist compare:[m_dtHistory objectAtIndex:i]] == NSOrderedDescending) {

}
```

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html